# React Native Sorting issue

Tags: arrays, sorting, react-native

I am fetching a JSON file and storing it in two arrays and sorting one of them by its rate as it shown below, unfortunately, it sorting the two arrays the recentPro and ratedPro but the desired array to be sorted is ratedPro only

```
fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          recentPro: responseJson.products,
          ratedPro:responseJson.products,  
        },
         function() {

           //Sort by rate
           const ratedpro= this.state.ratedPro.sort(function(a, b) {
            return Number(b.rate) - Number(a.rate);
        })
        this.setState({
            ratedPro: ratedpro,     
        })  

        })
```

Flat List

```
<FlatList
                data={this.state.ratedPro}
                renderItem={this.mostrated}
                keyExtractor={item => item.pro_name}/>


<FlatList
                data={this.state.recentPro}
                renderItem={this.rederItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.pro_id} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning both `this.state.recentPro` and `this.state.ratedPro` to reference the same array. You are then mutating that array which will cause the change to be reflected in both `this.state.recentPro` and `this.state.ratedPro`, because both of these variables reference that same (now mutated) array.

You could shallow copy the array with `slice()` to achieve different sorting on the two arrays:

```
    this.setState({
      recentPro: responseJson.products.slice(),
      ratedPro:responseJson.products.slice(),  
    },
```

You're also triggering unnecessary and premature renders by calling `setState` multiple times, consider the following more concise solution which also deos some sanity checks on `response` to prevent your application from relying on the response of the API you are fetching data from:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    const { products } = responseJson

    if (products && Array.isArray(products)) {  
      const recentPro = products.slice()

      const ratedPro = products.slice().sort((a, b) => Number(b.rate) - Number(a.rate))

      this.setState({
        recentPro,
        ratedPro,  
      })
    } else { /* display error to user */ }
  }
```